# Can select the nearest point to a table of points but I also need the point name

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have two spatial tables, `sp1` has points representing houses, `pt2` has points representing public transport.

I want to find the nearest public transport for each house. I have it nearly working but I can't seem to get the name of the public transport into the `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT 
    sp1.spaddressid, 
    MIN(ST_Distance(sp1.spgeom,pt2.geom)/1000) As "Distance from address to nearest public transport"
FROM 
    public."address" sp1, 
    public."dublin_pubtrans_itm" pt2
GROUP BY sp1.spaddressid
;
```

The query is working fine, but I would like to get the nearest public transport name (`pt2.name`) to display. Anytime I try to add it in I get:

```
ERROR: column "pt2.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 1: SELECT sp1.spaddressid, pt2.name AS "Name", MIN(ST_Distance(...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably to skip the aggregate function use altogether and instead use the DISTINCT ON construction, something like the below should give you one row for each address with the nearest public transit item referenced on the same row:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(sp1.spaddressid) sp1.spaddressid
 , (ST_Distance(sp1.spgeom,pt2.geom)/1000) AS "Distance from address to nearest public transport"
 , pt2.name AS "nearest public transport name"

FROM public."address" sp1, public."dublin_pubtrans_itm" pt2
ORDER BY sp1.spaddressid
 , (ST_Distance(sp1.spgeom,pt2.geom)/1000) ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lateral join:

```
SELECT sp1.spaddressid, pt2.dist / 1000, pt2.name
FROM public.address AS sp1
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT sp1.spgeom <-> pt.geom,
             pt.name
      FROM public.dublin_pubtrans_itm AS pt
      ORDER BY 1
      LIMIT 1
   ) AS pt2;
```

It won't be very fast though.

Comment: Thanks Lauernz Abe.

Comment: for index driven *KNN* searches, this is the correct way; but you definetely want to use the (PostGIS own) `<->` operator, e.g. `... ORDER BY sp1.geom <-> sp2.geom ...` for that!

Comment: That's right. I have improved the answer, thank you.